# Generic based on existence of method

Tags: java

Is it possible, in java, to have a generic based on the existence of a function rather then class or interface?

Example:
Let's say that I have a few classes that I have no control over.
They do not extend or implement any class in common, but all have the method getCode.

And I would like to create a single cache that can store instances of any of those classes:

```java
public class MyClass1 {
  public String getCode() {
      return "A";
  }
  // some other methods
}
```

```java
public class MyClass2 {
  public String getCode() {
      return "B";
  }

  // some other methods
}
```

```java
public class CodeBasedCache<ClassWithGetCode> {
  
  Map<String, Object> cache = new HashMap<>();
  
  public Object get(ClassWithGetCode obj) {
      return cache.get(obj.getClass().getSimpleName() + obj.getCode());
  }

  public void put(ClassWithGetCode obj) {
      cache.put(obj.getClass().getSimpleName() + obj.getCode(), obj);
  }
}
```

I am aware that I could use reflection to solve this issue by doing something like:

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class CodeBasedCache {

    Map<String, Object> cache = new HashMap<>();

    public Object get(Object obj) {
        try {
            String code = (String) obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getCode", null).invoke(obj, null);
            return cache.get(obj.getClass().getSimpleName() + code);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void put(Object obj) {
        try {
            String code = (String) obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getCode", null).invoke(obj, null);
            cache.put(obj.getClass().getSimpleName() + code, obj);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

However this solution will not give compilation error if someone tries to call the put with an Object that does not have the method getCode, throwing only a runtime exception if that happens, which is not ideal.

I ask this, because I have implemented something similar in TypeScript, and was wondering if in java (maybe on one of the latest versions), this would be possible.

Comment: No, I don't think Java's type system supports what you want to do.

Comment: If the list of classes you need is fixed, you could just enumerate them with overloaded methods: `public Object get(MyClass1 obj)`, `public Object get(MyClass2 obj)` etc.

Comment: Don't think it is possible. You can check on any class if a method with a given name and signature is implemented by using reflection, but as to my knowledge there is no way of knowing about *any* classes that could possibly be loaded from *somewhere*.

Comment: No, that's not possible. The behavior you're describing is exactly what an interface is for. If there is any way you can create an interface with the `getCode()` method and make all of these classes inherit from the interface, then this is fairly trivial. If not, you will have to use reflection.

Comment: I other languages, that's called duck typing, and no Java definitely does not support it.